# node js express - how to serve a static content for variable urls

Tags: node.js, static, express, routes

The [app.use documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) shows examples of serving a static directory for static routes, e.g.

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

What is the syntax for specifying that a static directory should be served for non-static routes?

Going by the syntax elsewhere (app.get, etc.) it would seem like `app.use('/:foo', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` should work. However, I always get a `Cannot GET /bar` error.

Comment: You lost me, either you have a directory with static files that actually match the filenames the browser is requesting, or you have defined routes that creates the content the browser is requesting, how do you have a static directory for non-static requests ?

Comment: There is one directory with the site's content that I want to serve for xyz.com, xyz.com/a, xyz.com/b, etc. (I didn't decide this design.)

Comment: This question was in service of [this github contribution](https://github.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/pull/233), btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`res.sendfile()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile) for variable paths to point to the same static content:

```
app.get('/:location', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep all the functionality that comes with [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), then you can just monkey-patch `req.url` (since it's just middleware):

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Dynamic path, but only match asset at specific segment.
app.use('/static/:foo/:bar/:asset', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = req.params.asset;
  express.static(__dirname + '/static')(req, res, next);
});         

// Just the asset.
app.use('/static/*', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = path.basename(req.originalUrl);
  express.static(__dirname + '/static')(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After having the same question, I've come up with the following solution:

```
app.use('/path/:file', function (req, res, next) {
  return express.static(require('path').join('.', 'path', req.params.file)).apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: is this just a fancy way of saying `return express.static('path.' + req.params.file)`?

Comment: https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/#use-path-join-to-join-folder-names

Comment: I understand join, just not the use of apply

Comment: I can't remember for sure anymore (have been more then an year since I used Node.js), but I believe it had something to do with not blocking routes. You can find an example use here: https://github.com/jerone/PackageSize/blob/master/routes/routesStatic.js#L42 Don't know how valid this is anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ralf, I think what you are looking for is "views". If you want your site to route "non-static", then leave `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` as is.

And set views like this:

```
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
```

of course you'll need to handle routes that user tries to get.
You need to explore: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

I use Couchdb I will show you example it might help.

```
app.get('/:foo', function(req, res){
if (!err){
res.render('htmlname', {
title: 'somedata'
});
}}
```

Hope it helped, Goodluck

Comment: Thanks, but there are no views. There is a static set of content to serve, regardless of url used.